# Really Sporadic Unity Behavior? No Idea What is Causing it

Tags: macos, debugging, unity-game-engine

So I have Unity 5 for Mac, I'm on OS X 10.11, and I'm using MonoDevelop. Over the past week or so this glitch, bug, whatever it is has been getting more and more annoying to the point where it is now. Currently I have 1 script running and when I play my project 2 things happen:

1. The script doesn't run! I have it outputting a ton of things and it doesn't output anything or do what it is supposed to. I've tried refreshing the assets and everything, but after the first run, nothing
2. There is an even stranger thing happening. I have a RawImage used to display the webcam and a plane far far away from this RawImage. I am making a custom material for this plane that only has white and red. Nonetheless, this plane also shows the webcam. There is no code or property connecting the 2 whatsoever.

These 2 events always happen together. Now I have to restart Unity almost every run to fix this. I'll run it once, maybe twice, sometimes even 3 times and it will work perfectly fine then the next time it will do these things. Sometimes after running it another few times it will switch back. Sometimes I'll run it 10 or 15 times and it doesn't go back and I have to restart Unity. **Has anyone run into any form of this very strange bug / glitch before?**

**[EDIT]** Here is the code that might be causing the problem. This code is called in the Start method:

```
IEnumerator TakePicAndGetBestColor() {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);

    print ("here");

    if (webcamTexture.width > 100) {

        print ("HERE");

        initFrame = webcamTexture.GetPixels ();
        currentFrame = initFrame;

        print ("waiting again");

        if (initFrame [0].r >= 0.999f || initFrame [0].g >= 0.999f || initFrame [0].b >= 0.999f) {

            print ("waiting");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);

        }

        sorterThread = new Thread (() => TrackPhone.SortColors(initFrame));
        print ("started");
        sorterThread.Start ();

    }

}
```

It prints up to "here," but doesn't print "HERE."

Here are some screenshots:
My setup:
[image: My setup]
The canvas when it is played:
[image: Canvas]
The plane (looking down) when it is played (it SHOULDN'T look like this):
[image: Plane]
What it should look like:
[image: Plane 2]

I have found no reason why the plane should have the webcam texture. Nothing in script or in Unity.

Comment: "using MonoDevelop" strongly recommend, just get TextWrangler (it's even free).

Comment: Yes the script is attached to the RawImage. It runs sometimes, but other times it doesn't. It's always attached, even when it doesn't run. Also, the webcam code is long, however, I'll add the code that I thing might be causing the problem.

Comment: @JoeBlow I added the code.

Comment: @JoeBlow but the behavior is still unpredictable.

Comment: Most of the code is missing, it's hard to tell anything from what you show here. I'm also not sure I understand perfectly the gfx glitch described in text. Could you record a video and link here or something?

Comment: I recorded videos but I'll have to wait to host them somewhere.

Comment: @JoeBlow I added some screenshots.

Comment: @Mark I added some screenshots.